# mud keeps drying and crumbling as i spread it on wall

Tags: mudding

i have mixed mud as close as possible to the correct consistency of cake frosting, and have studied many you tube videos to see what the pros do, but every time i apply the mud it seems to dry and crumble as i spread it with a taping knife. then the only way i can smooth it out is by brushing over it with a wet brush, otherwise it becomes stiff and hard to spread on wall. if i force it it starts to tear and dry. if i mix it to the same consistency as those on you tube, why does it become dry and stiff as i use it. when i see it done on you tube, they seem to spread it like cream on the wall, never drying out, almost like they have added oil to the mud. what can i do to make it smooth on easily. i have resorted to wetting the wall before applying it, but i find that this just washes away any previous layer of mud i added.

Comment: It sounds like you might be using some sort of quick-setting material. Tell us **exactly** what you are using and what you are trying to do.

Comment: You might get that if youre using 5 minute mud, but chances are you just need a little more water.

Comment: Sounds like plaster of paris....

Answer (score 3):

If this is for a small home project stop with trying to mix drywall compound yourself and purchase the premixed material in the plastic bucket.

Answer (score 1):

From a diy'er who has made a mess of a lot of walls by trial and error, here is a hint.  A cream consistency of 'mud' works for pros who mix and move the stuff fast with a lot of experience and a deft swirl of the wrist. For the rest of is it needs to be pretty thin, just thick enough to stay on the trowel, even if it drips a bit on to the drop cloth. Spread with an upward motion, overlapping as little as possible. The thinner it goes on, the better. You may think that multiple coats is a lot more work. It is actually a lot LESS work. Put it on as thin as you can manage, work relatively fast and by the time you've covered a good area the first part will be nearly dry. When it is dry to the touch enough that you don't leave a print in it, then you can put on another thin coat. I've put on as many as four coats very thin, come back when almost completely dry and wiped it gently with an almost completely dry sponge and ended up with almost no sanding to do. If you are after a mirror smooth finish, you'll have to sand carefully. Otherwise this works fine for the average household work and saves a lot of crumbled, wasted mud and a lot of crumbled patience as well.  Good luck.
...  The very thin mud may take several coats but in my experience ends up going as far as (or sometimes farther than) trying to apply one or two thick coats. If you use small batch pre-mix, get the kind that is almost foamy in texture. It can be pressed into the cracks better, does not shrink or crack as much.  Want to eliminate the cracking? Dilute and put on more coats.

Comment: Biggest downfall to thinning it up is the shrinkage.

Comment: the mud settles quick, so when on the trowel, you need to practice the re-shaping/mixing technique done by the pro's, i.e you must basically re-mix every piece you apply, then its nice and spongy and ready to stick.